# Issue saving xml file with LXML. Encoding issue not showing Symbol from original xml file

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

I have a xml file with symbols like `®`. When I open the xml and save it using lxml I now see `&#174;` instead. I've tried setting the encoding on the parser, has not made a difference. I'm wondering if there is anything specific I need to do to maintain the symbols as they are?

Example:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, encoding='utf-8')
return etree.parse(path, parser)
```

Comment: How do you save the XML tree? When using `tree.write("symbol.xml", encoding="utf-8")`, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I found a issue in my save. This is no longer a issue for me.